# Typescript Runtime Errors

Tags: javascript, class, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am relatively new to javascript/typescript and I'm getting a runtime error that I don't quite understand. I'm trying to create an instance of a TrailingAvg class, but my code breaks when i decalre it and produces a javascript runtime error - TrailingAvg is undefined. I though I set up the classes correctly and the syntax is being accepted, but I can't create this instance. What do I need to do to create an instance of a class in Typescript?

```
function drawChart(n) {
        uri = getURLParameter("url");
        setupHeader();
        setupMenu();
        var totalcount = 5;
        var prevmonth = 0;
        var trail = new TrailingAvg(n); //run time error here

    }
class TrailingAvg {
    totals: number[] = [];
    average: number;
    size: number;
    constructor(n: number) {
        this.size = n;
    }
    push(month, prevmonth, value) {
        var zeroes = month - prevmonth;
        for (var i = 0; i < zeroes; i++) {
            this.totals.shift();
            this.totals.push(0);
        }

        this.totals.push(value);
    }
    getAvg() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.totals.length; i++) {
            this.average = this.average + this.totals[i];

        }
        return this.average;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class definition must come *before* any code that attempts to use it. This usually goes wrong in one of two ways:

### Oops, I have two files now

Problem: You have `foo.ts` and decide to split it into `foo.ts` and `bar.ts`. This compiles into `foo.js` and `bar.js`, but your HTML page only says

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

Solution: Fix your HTML page to have the additional script tag:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
<script src="bar.js"></script>
```

### What's script ordering?

Problem: You have `animal.ts` and `cat.ts`, where `cat.ts` has some dependency on `animal.ts`. You write your HTML as:

```
<script src="cat.js"></script>
<script src="animal.js"></script>
```

and get a runtime error about something from `animal.ts` being undefined. This is because scripts execute in the order given in the page.

Solution: Order your files in dependency order:

```
<script src="animal.js"></script>
<script src="cat.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was the problem, I had the scripts out of order. Thank you!